# python -m django startproject vs django-admin startproject

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

hi everyone what is difference between `python -m django startproject` and

```
django-admin startproject
```

if it have any different so which one is better for use ?

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

They are about the same, with `manage.py` doing the same as `django-admin`, but setting the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable beforehand.

## Answer

`django-admin` is a script installed by `setuptools` when installing `django` (i.e: `pip install django`). The script generated executes something similar to (but not exactly):

```py
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

You can see its definition in [setup.cfg:48](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/setup.cfg#L48), where there's an entrypoint defined to run the function `django.core.management:execute_from_command_line`.

Similarly, `manage.py` looks something like:

```py
...imports

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "yourproject.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

So, as the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/) say: `manage.py` is automatically generated and does the same as `django-admin`, but it sets the module `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable.